# How to concatenate multiple queries in a single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the table below, I wonder if it's possible to create a single query (for performance reasons) that provides the result I am looking for. Here is an example of such table:

| id | score | cond | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item-1 | 37.5 | true | ... |
| item-2 | 40.4 | true | ... |
| item-3 | 12.3 | false | yesterday |
| item-4 | 55.9 | true | ... |
| item-5 | 20.1 | false | 1 week ago |

The result that I am looking for is the list of ids ordered by the following criteria:

- First, the ids where `cond` is `False`, ordered by `timestamp`, where the newest ones come first. For this query, I am able to use something like:

  - `SELECT id FROM table WHERE cond is false ORDER BY timestamp`
- Second, the ids where `cond` is `True`, ordered by `score`, where the highest score comes first. For this query, I am able to use something like:

  - `SELECT id FROM table WHERE cond is true ORDER BY score DESC`

The resulting table would be something like this:

| id | score | cond | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item-3 | 12.3 | false | yesterday |
| item-5 | 20.1 | false | 1 week ago |
| item-4 | 55.9 | true | ... |
| item-2 | 40.4 | true | ... |
| item-1 | 37.5 | true | ... |

What should I do to have the results of both queries in a single query? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use  "UNION ALL".

```
select * from 
(
  (SELECT id FROM table WHERE cond is false ORDER BY timestamp)
   UNION ALL
  (SELECT id FROM table WHERE cond is true ORDER BY score DESC)
) as newtable
```

Answer (score 0):

It organizes the table by the order you put it in the `order by` clause. First the condition (`false` then `true`), then `date` and after that `score`.

```
select   *
from     t
order by cond, case when cond = 'false' then "timestamp"  end desc, score
```

| id | score | cond | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| item-3 | 12.3 | false | yesterday |
| item-5 | 20.1 | false | 1 week ago |
| item-4 | 55.9 | true | ... |
| item-2 | 40.4 | true | ... |
| item-1 | 37.5 | true | ... |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a0b2f6e2d614639a59aeef11f5db524e)

Comment: see updated answer